# problema con argv en c

Tags: c

Estoy escribiendo un programa para para recorrer uno de los argumentos y almacenarlos en una variable, pero me da un error de segmentación justo en este bucle:

```
 for(int i=0; argv[1][i] != "\0" ;i++){
    }
```

¿De qué otra forma podría recorrer argv para evitar este error?

Comment: Y ¿Por qué no revisas `ctype.h` o `string.h`?

así usas `strcpy(variable[x], argv[x]);`

Y con `ctype.h`  usas `atoi(argumento)` para convertirlo a entero, o `atof()` para flotante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haces una comparación incorrecta. Seguramente, el compilador te de un aviso (*warning*).

`argv[1][i] != "\0"` estas comparando un `char` con un *puntero*. Bueno, en realidad el compilador *promociona* `argv[1][i]` a `int`, así que, en realidad, estas comparando un `int` con un *puntero*.

Para lo que quieres hacer, puedes usar

```
argv[1][i] != 0
```

o

```
argv[1][i] != '\0' // Comillas simples '
```

Recuerda que, en C, las cadenas entre comillas dobles `"..."` no son mas que *arreglos* de caracteres. Al usarlas, en realidad usas su **dirección**, es decir, un *puntero*.

Comment: Vale, ya entiendo... Muchas gracias @Trauma :D